# Where to find flat icons for formatting?

Tags: icon, resource-recommendations

I want to create a tool bar with the following items:

- Browse
- Templates
- New document
- Copy
- Paste
- Cut
- Fill
- Save
- Undo / Redo
- Line Color

I've been looking everywhere for a free icon set with the above. The icon sets I keep finding were social media icon sets, weather icon sets or people icon sets. The relevant icons I found were either too bulky or didn't seem like they were from the same set.

Can anyone suggest where I can get good formatting icons? Also I'm wondering where to find flat icons similar to the formatting toolbar in Ms Word 2013.

[image]

[**Link**](http://images.pcworld.com/images/article/2012/07/4_word_2013_2-11385480.jpg)

Comment: Did you google 'ui icon sets'? I don't mean to be flippant, but there are literally dozens of web sites dedicated to curating and selling (or giving away) sets of UI icons. The second result in seaching that is "452 free flat icon sets": http://www.flaticon.com/packs/

Answer (score 1):

Depending on wether this is commercial use or not, you might want to check out [**Icomoon.**](https://icomoon.io/) Be aware and pay heed to the licensing.

In any instance, you might want to search for something like "free svg icons" or something to that effect.